# How can I add numbers to array simply using unshift()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I add numbers to an array upside down using 'unshift()'??

I'd like to get an array = {2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, ... , 1999}.
because '2018' is this year and '1999' is the debut year of a singer I like. 
And that's why I'm starting with '1999' which is array[0].

Here is my code using 'push()'. I think it's too long and stupid. I believe there is something I can't come up with. Thank you.

```
<script>
          var years = [1999];
          var i = 0;
          var n = new Date().getFullYear() - years[i] + 1;
          while(i < n){
            years.push(years[i]+1);
            i++;
          }
          i=1;
          years.reverse();
          while(i < years.length){
            document.write('<li><a href='+years[i]+'.html>'+years[i]+'</a></li>');
            i++;
          }
        </script>
```

Comment: If your code works and you want to improve it, this question is not really suited for this site. I suggest you go to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you want to create an array of numbers listing all numbers between two numbers, you'll have to create a loop. `unshift()` can't just guess the numbers to fill.

Comment: @Zenoo that's true, but with unshift there would be no reverse.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca Actually, it works. I just wanted to make it shorter and better. 'Code Review SE' is a web site for practicing?

Comment: Nope, it's a website to have your code reviewed by other developer who will give you suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Oh, I see. really nice for me to know that. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var years = [1999];
var i = 0;
var n = new Date().getFullYear() - years[i];
while (i < n) {
  years.unshift(years[0]+1);
  i++;
}
console.log(years);
```

This adds the next year to the beginning of the array with `unshift()` like you wanted. This removes the need to reverse the array like you did.

Noteworthy here is that we always unshift the value of `years[0]+1` since the the array is reversed making the largest number always at index 0.

Comment: You don't really need the counter, you could set n as the current year and do it while (years[0] < n).

Comment: @maraca yeah, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even need an array at all?

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (var year = currentYear; year >= 1999; year--){
  document.write('<li><a href='+year+'.html>'+year+'</a></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I modify your code to generate `years` in array. That should be like this with initial year i.e **debutYear**

```js
this.years = function(debutYear) {
            var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(), years = [];
            while ( debutYear <= currentYear ) {
                    years.push(debutYear++);
            } 
            return years.reverse();
    }

console.log(years(1999));
```

Comment: This will require `return years.reverse()` to fully meet the OP's requirement.

Comment: Edited as per your suggestions. Thnx :)